# convert from jpg to png and back several times (quality loss?)

Tags: imagemagick

With imagemagick one can convert images from one format to another. Is the conversion from jpg to png and from png to jpg (that is, converting to png to make several changes in the image, and converting back to jpg to reduce the image size) a problem concerning quality loss?

Can we convert thousands of times an image back and forth jpg->png and png->jpg without losing quality?

The command is: 
convert image.jpg -quality 100% image.png 
and
convert image.png -quality 100% image.jpg

Comment: How is this about Ubuntu? I suggest that the better place for your question is: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Note: It may be found off-topic there because it's not about photography.

Comment: There is also https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ as a possibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG is a lossy compression format, and PNG isn't.  Each time you re-compress using JPEG you will suffer further quality loss.

To prevent this, always perform editing on an original copy of the image that has never been compressed using JPEG, and then compress to JPEG only the copy that you will be outputting/sending.  Keep the original if you want to do further modifications later.